# Can't deploy me Next.js project

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages, next.js13

I build my Next.js project and push it to GitHub and now I want deploy it to GitHub Pages but while I'm trying to do it I got errors **Module not found:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnWP8.png)

In my localhost all work properly

What can I do with it and where I do wrong?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)